# How to count words in array of strings in java?

Tags: java

I am learning about arrays and I wanted to make a program count words. Given: `String myWords = {"soon; hi; also; soon; job; also"};`
, I have to create a method like `countWrods(myWords);` 
The printed result should be the words printed alphabetical order, the number of unique words and total words. 
here is my code:

```
public class Words {
    public static  void main(String[] args){    
        String[] myWords = {"soon; hi; also; soon; job; mother; job; also; soon; later"};
        Words myW= new Words();
        myW.countWords();
        System.out.println("\tWords   \tFreq");
    }
    public  static String[] countWords(myWords){
        for (int i=0; i<myWords.length; i++){
        String temp = myWords[i];
        //System.out.println(temp + " ");
        for(int j=i+1; j<myWords.length; j++){
        String temp2= myWords[j];

            System.out.println("No. of unique words: " );
        }
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do next?

Comment: Your array of strings only contains one element. Just saying. (Could be one String)

Comment: Are you actually trying to do `String[] myWords = {"soon", "hi", "also", "soon", "job", "mother", "job", "also", "soon", "later"};`

Comment: See [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking, I think you're not consistent with first, third and fourth points.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Count_Words_Scan
{
    void main()throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("ENTER A STRING ");
        String str = br.readLine();
        str= str.toLowerCase();
        int c=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            sc.next();
            c++;
        }
        System.out.println("NO.OF WORDS = "+c);
    }
}
```

Input: the word counter
Output: NO.OF WORDS = 3

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a look at [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) and [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to count the words in a string .

**String** : `"soon hi also soon job mother job also soon later"`

```
 public class Words {

Map<String , Integer> dictionary=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myWords = "soon hi also soon job mother job also soon later";
    Words myW = new Words();
    String[] array=myWords.split("\\s+");
    myW.countWords(array);
    System.out.println(myW.dictionary);
}

private void countWords(String[] myWords) {

    for(String s:myWords){

        if(dictionary.containsKey(s))
            dictionary.put(s, dictionary.get(s)+1);
        else
            dictionary.put(s, 1);
    }
}
}
```

`O/P : {mother=1, later=1, job=2, hi=1, also=2, soon=3}`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to split your `String`, presumably on ";" - then you can whack that into a `TreeSet` to sort it and make then words unqiue. Add a counter to count the total words. You could also use a `TreeMap` to keep a count of each word, override the put method on the map to aggregate as you go...

```
final String myString = {"soon; hi; also; soon; job; mother; job; also; soon; later"};
final String[] myStrings = myString.split(";");
final Map<String, Integer> myStringMap = new TreeMap<>(){
 @override
 public String put(final String key, final Integer value) {
   if(contains(key)) {
     return put(key, get(key) + 1);
   } else {
     return put(key, 1);
   } 
 }
};
for(final String string : myStrings) {
  myStringMap.put(string.trim(), 1);
}
```

Now `myStringMap.size()` is the number of unique words, `myStringMap.keys()` is a alphabetically sorted `Set` of all unquie words and if you want the total you just need to add up the values:

```
int totalWords = 0;
for(final Integer count : myStringMap.values()) {
  totalWorks += count;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all, I am working on that and I will let you know the progress.