# Cannot count number in ArrayList using java

Tags: java

I am using the List as shown below:-

```
List<Integer> integerlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

integerlist=primeFactors(numberToBERadical);
```

The primeFactors method return me some number when i sysOut as:-

```
System.out.println("integer list=="+integerlist);
integer list==[2, 2, 2, 3, 5]
```

My Problem is i want to count how many time that each number appears so that i can show Like this:-

```
2^3 * 3 * 5
```

Comment: How about using a Map instead of a List?

Comment: Use a `Map<Integer,Integer>` key is the prime, and the value is incremented for every occurrence of the prime.

Comment: Thanks for replying, can u give me Some more details so that i can implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is sorted, you can count them like:

```
int count = 0;
int last = 0; // zero is not possible for prime-factors
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
    if(i == 0 || last == list.get(i)) count++;
    else {
        if(last > list.get(0)) {
            System.out.print(" * ");
        }

        System.out.print(last + (count > 1 ? "^" + count: ""));
        count = 1;
    }
    last = list.get(i);
}
//print last sequence.
if(last > 0) {
    if(last > list.get(0)) {
        System.out.print(" * ");
    }

    System.out.print(last + (count > 1 ? "^" + count: ""));
}
```

Comment: I was demonstrating an idea... well I updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to associate each factor with the number of times it occurs (the exponent).

To do that, a better data structure than a List would be a `Map<Integer,Integer>`.

Let's assume you still get a `List` from your `primeFactors(numberToBERadical);` (assuming you can't change it or don't want to for some reason).

You can do something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(2);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(5);

    Map<Integer, Integer> factors = new HashMap<>();
    for(Integer fact: list){
        if(!factors.containsKey(fact)) { factors.put(fact, 1);}
        else {
            Integer value = factors.get(fact);
            factors.put(fact, ++value);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(factors);
}
```

Prints: `{2=3, 3=2, 5=1}`

Comment: Sir does not  work correctly. though my list was [2, 2, 2, 3, 5], i used your method above but factors variable give me ==> {2=1, 3=1, 5=1} which should be {2=3,3=1,5=1}

Comment: Just tested and printed the results, with a little refactor

Answer (score 1):

One possible, but not the simplest solution:

```
public Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> primeFactors(List<Integer integerList) {
  final Map<Integer, AtomicInteger> count = new HashMap<Integer, AtomicInteger>();

  for (final Integer number : integerlist) {
    if (count.containsKey(number)) {
      count.get(number).incrementAndGet();
    } else {
      count.put(number, new AtomicInteger(1));
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` which you can override the `put` method in in order to count the instances of each `Integer`.

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> myStringMap = new HashMap<>(){
 @override
 public String put(final Integer key, final Integer value) {
   if(contains(key)) {
     return put(key, get(key) + 1);
   } else {
     return put(key, 1);
   } 
 }
};
```

You could even use a `TreeMap` to have the prime factors sorted by size. I answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936107/count-words-in-array-of-string-in-java/14936425#14936425). Simply loop over your `List` and dump it into the map

```
for(final Integer integer : myList) {
  myCountingMap.put(integer, 1);
}
```

Even better would be to change your factorising method to return a `Map` to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> inputList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    inputList.add(2);
    inputList.add(2);
    inputList.add(2);
    inputList.add(3);
    inputList.add(3);
    inputList.add(4);

    Map<Integer, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    boolean flag = false;

    for(int val : inputList)
    {
        if(resultMap.get(val) == null)
        {
            resultMap.put(val, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            resultMap.put(val, (resultMap.get(val).intValue())+1);
        }
    }

    for(int key : resultMap.keySet())
    {
        if(resultMap.get(key) == 1)
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                System.out.print(key);
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("*"+key);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!flag)
            {
                System.out.print(key+"^"+resultMap.get(key));
                flag = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("*"+key+"^"+resultMap.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
```